# cordova save contact if not exist by phone number

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to save phonebook (with phone number as primary index) contact when it doesn't exist.

I have tried to check the contact with navigator. contacts. finds ()`, and check length is 0 (if not in contact, save contact) but seems it does not work.

sometime my ionic app will save double (or more than 2) contact in the phonebook, and it will like, 103 same phone numbers in my phonebook.

code :

```
var app = {
  initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
  },
  onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    document.getElementById("call").addEventListener("click", ayam);
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
  },
  receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
  }
};

app.initialize();
function dialogAlert() {
  var message = "Sync Android Contact has been activated!";
  var title = "Info";
  var buttonName = "Close";
  navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, title, buttonName);
  function alertCallback() {
    console.log("Alert is Dismissed!");
  }
}

function ayam() {
  if($(".aba").val().length > 3) {
    setInterval(function(){
      kambing();
    }, 5000); // recheck server every 5 second
    dialogAlert();
  }
  else {
    alert("Write your API Url !");
  }
}

function kambing(){
  var url = $(".aba").val();
  $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : url + "/save",
    dataType : 'html',
    success: function(response){
      var hp = response
        ,   anu = hp.split(",");
      anu.forEach(function(v){
        save_contact(v);
      })
    },
    error : function() {
      alert("Failed to fetch url");
    }
  });
}

function save_contact(xs){
  var pn = xs.replace(/\D/g,'');
  if(pn.length > 3) {
    var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter   = xs;
    options.multiple = true;
    options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id];
    options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
    var fields       = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.phoneNumbers];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);

    function onSuccess(contacts) {
      if(contacts.length < 1) {
        var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "The New Contact"});
        var name = new ContactName();
        name.givenName = xs;
        myContact.name = name;

        var phoneNumbers = [];
        //phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('work', '212-555-1234', false);
        phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('mobile', pn, true); // preferred number
        //phoneNumbers[2] = new ContactField('home', '203-555-7890', false);
        myContact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
        myContact.note = "Helo";
        myContact.save(sukses, elor);
        function sukses(contact) {
          //alert("saved")
          $.ajax({
            url   : url,
            type  : 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data  : {wdyw:0,title:content,isanony:isanony,category:category,url:url},
            beforeSend  : function(){
              //$("#loading").show();
            },
            success : function(result){

              $('[name="content"]').val('');
              $('[name="content"]').val('Pertanyaan anda telah terkirim :)');
              setTimeout(function(){$('[name="content"]').val('');},500);
            }
          });
        };
        function elor(contactError) {};
      }
    };

    function onError(contactError) {
      return false;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: sorry @RobAnthony , done

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i'm not getting error, but idk, sometime the app will save multiple contact with same phone number, huff @Sheldon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite to ionic, (because more stable)